# Rails_admin show child models fields in parents show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have `Item` model and I have `ItemImage` child model which is embedded inside of its parent.

When I open single `Items` page in rails_admin, it shows all of its children like this:

`ItemImage #55b766556c656e12d0ac0000, ItemImage #55b766556c656e12d0ad0000, and ItemImage #55b766566c656e12d0ae0000`

How to make `rails_admin` to show all of its children fields inside parents page? Is it possible to show them as table?

I'm using Mongoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made very simple solution. I have added `def name` method into my model:

```
 def name
   "<a href=\"#{self.image_url}\"><img src=\"#{self.image_url(:thumb)}\" /></a>"
 end
```

It shows me Images of embedded models inside parents page. I know that it is not good solution but only that I have found.